# Run bash script after logon is made

Tags: bash, gnome, ubuntu-18.04

I want to run a .sh script once whenever a logon is made (including logons made after a suspend)

It should run in the background, so no shell poping up

The script is the following

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash script to refresh the Extend Panel Menu extension that puts the clock in the wrong place after logon

gnome-shell-extension-tool -d extend-panel-menu@julio641742

sleep 1

gnome-shell-extension-tool -e extend-panel-menu@julio641742
```

It just refreshes an extension that I have in Ubunto 18.04 that gets misconfigured in every logon I do.

How can I make it run automatically after those logons?

Comment: This really sounds like an XY problem. It seems like your efforts would be more wisely spent to fix the buggy extension so the clock doesn't wander around in the first place.

Comment: Could you not just call the script as a ["Startup Application"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)?

Comment: I usually add a startup script `$HOME/bin/autostart.sh` into xfce4-settings->session&startup->application autostart. That way I just add all my Xserver thinks into one script. One can just create a .desktop file inside `$HOME/.config/autostart`, probably gnome should pickup it

Comment: @JNevill In this case, if I suspend the computer and then wake it up and do the logon will it run the script? Or will it run the script just when I boot the system?

Comment: @glennjackman I'd love to fix it but I'm new to this universe of linux (and that was the first script i made in bash). So I don't think i'm capable of fixing this bug.